# bash date last with week number

Tags: bash, shell, date

To get the date of the last sunday one could use `date --date="last sun"` for Linux and `date -j -v-sun` for BSD.

How is it done however if I do have week numbers (1 to 7) instead of strings? I could always use a case-statement to convert the numbers to strings, but I bet there is a better solution for this?!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array:

```
number=1
days=(zero sun mon tue wed thu fri sat)
date --date="last ${days[number]}"
```